# CodeIgniter pagination not working for get method

Tags: codeigniter, pagination, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I needed pagination with get parameters. In the method I've written following code as follows.

```
public function index($offset = 0) {

    $data['title_for_layout'] = 'Apartment Advertisement - Search';


    // Pagination config
    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $pagination['enable_query_strings'] = true;
    $pagination['page_query_string'] = true;
    $pagination['allow_get_array'] = true;
    $pagination['first_url'] = base_url('search');
    $pagination['base_url'] = $config['first_url'];
    $pagination['total_rows'] = $this->aa_movies->no_of_search_movies();
    $data['no_of_results'] = $pagination['total_rows'];
    $pagination['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $pagination['per_page'] = 20;

    // Initialize pagination
    $this->pagination->initialize($pagination);

    // Offset
    $offset = 20 * $offset;

    // Get apartments
    $data['apartments'] = $this->aa_movies->search_movies($this->input->get('keyword'), $this->input->get('city'), $this->input->get('locations'), $offset);

    $this->load->view($this->config->item('index_search_view'), $data);
}
```

In view

```
<?php echo form_open(base_url('search'), array('method' => 'get'); ?>
<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

So the pagination url looks like

```
http://localhost/reelstubs/search/1
```

But I wanted in pagination url as follows

```
http://localhost/reelstubs/search?keyword=complex&city=bangalore&page=1
```

Even I tried changing pagination base_url by including $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. But the url looks like

```
http://localhost/reelstubs/search?keyword=complex&city=bangalore/1
```

So I'm not getting the page no using `$this->uri->segment();` Please help me to get over this. Its been 2 days I've wasted on this. The work would be more appreciated.

Comment: nstead of using `$this->uri->segment();`, try something like thsi  `$this->input->get("page")`

Answer (score 0):

1. You can add your filtering string (keyword and city) in hidden inputs and get those values using $this->input->get('name')
2. Or You can send a necessary values in segment and get it using $this->uri->segment();

   `http://localhost/search/method(func)/complex/bangalore/1`

   $keyword = $this->uri->segment('3');
   $city = $this->uri->segment('4');
   $page = $this->uri->segment('5');

Answer (score 0):

Use the [CodeIgniter 3.0](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Pagination.php) version of the Pagination Library. It has a config option to reuse the query string.

I've implemented it myself in a CodeIgniter 2, but rather than replace the distributed version , I deployed it as an overloaded library called MY_Pagination and placed it in my 'application/libraries' folder. The only code change I had to do to make this work this way was to set the access modifiers to public rather than protected.